# ASP.NET 5 Self-Host

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-1.0, self-hosting

I Have a project in ASP.NET 5 using self-host.

**PROJECT.JSON**

```
"commands": {
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
"gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
"ef":  "EntityFramework.Commands"
},
```

It using the http://localhost:5000...

I want to know how can i acess the website from another PC, not using localhost. Like a IP with or without DNS.

Please, help me!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue trying to self host and only being able to access locally. I checked with Angry IP Scanner and saw that the port wasn't even open when the app was running so obviously that would prevent remote access.

Eventually I realised the `--server.urls` command must basically work like bindings in IIS, so where you have `--server.urls http://localhost:5000`, you just need to change `localhost` for your computer name or ip address (or add both) e.g. `--server.urls http://mypc:5000`.

This worked for me so I hope it does for you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question can be found here https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/799

> Change server.urls=http://localhost:5000 to server.urls=http://*:5000, but if you do that you'll need to run the process (or VS) as admin.

Answer (score 1):

You should allow incoming connections for your application:

First, start an administrative command prompt. Second, run these commands, replacing yourip:yourport with whatever IP and port you are using:

> netsh http add urlacl url=http://yourip:yourport/ user=everyone

This just tells http.sys that it’s ok to talk to this url.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make change in your firewall to allow it TCP connections on the port you expose (eg. 5000 in this case).
2. Your machine will have a machine name. So you can access the website from another machine using http://:5000/

Note that, you can access the machine only if the other machine is also in the same LAN network. Just use "ping " to quickly see if both the machines are in the same network.

Comment: I'll use my ip from ipconfig or my public ip to acess the website?

Comment: if you have a static IP it will work, but if you are behind NAT it will not.

Comment: i didnt have a static IP,,, I've created a rule for TCP into port 5000, now what i need to do to acess my site, i think i didnt understand why i need to do now... It just i put my IP from ipconfig in a browser and the port 5000 and acess?

Comment: Where is the second machine? Is it part of the same network? If yes, just type in the IP:port or machinename:port and you should be able to see the website.

Comment: if i try to acess from the same machine i'll recieve an error? I necessary need to use another machine to try to acess my website? When i try to acess with my ip (192.168.0.128:5000) i got this message: Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

Comment: On your machine, your localhost is mapped with 127.0.0.1. So try with that.